# Delete function (imported from .py file) does not work in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code, import, jupyter-notebook

I am working within a .ipynb file in VS Code where I build my code for my master thesis project (i later copy them into .py files, when Im finished). The .py-file "f_functions" contains some functions that I use in multiple files.
I import it like this.

```
# Import #####
# Packages ###
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from copy import copy
import f_functions as ff
```

The code for the function in the "f_functions.py" file is like this.

```
def clean(data):
"""This function is used to remove variables/data objects that are no longer needed.
Its used to keep (especially the jupyter notebook variables viewer cleaner."""

try:
    del(data)
except:
    pass
```

When I then use the function in my .ipynb file, it doesnt delete the object that I want to delete. For example:

```
test = "test"
ff.clean(test)
```

When I write it like this:

```
test = "test"
try:
    del(test)
except:
    pass
```

It works.

So my question is: Why .ipynb files sometimes have trouble handling imported code? Or did I overlook something?

Comment: you are deleting a local variable in the function `clean`, there are other variables that have a reference to the data so it does not get deleted

Comment: how would i write the function, as to delete an object globally?

Comment: every function argument is a new reference to the data structure, there is no way you can remove the reference of the actual parameter of the function, why call `ff.clean(p)` if you can also write `del p`

Comment: because of the cell structure of Jupyter Notebooks and the way i tend to seperate a lot of steps in differnt cells, running a cell that contains del p when the variable was deleted already, causes an error. So I always would have to type the try-except-block also. I want to save coding time and keep the code cleaner this way.

Comment: `del` is not a function, so do not use `()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a variable `p` but you don't know if it already exists, you just assign anything to `p`, so type:

```python
p=0; del p
```

If you use a function you only delete the local variable.